# Showing image using im.show() not working in arch linux

Tags: python-imaging-library, ocr

I am learning OCR but when I started to code, I was able to import PIL and run the `Image.open()` command but when I tried to show it, it doesn,t work. I am using arch linux, endeavourOS to be precise and I am doing this on VScode in jupyter notebook.

I tried this:

```
image = "Datasets/Chem.jpg"
im = Image.open(image)
im.show()
```

and i got this :

```
line 745: 85756 Aborted                 (core dumped) "kde-open${KDE_SESSION_VERSION}" "$1"
```

Please help me to fix this

Answer (score 0):

I do not use ArchLinux and am unfamiliar with it. I suspect you can solve the issue by installing `eog` *"Eye of Gnome"*, or `xv` viewer. Have a read [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageShow.html).